# Understanding the difference between generator and basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

In my Linear Algebra script I have this passage here:

> For $b_1,\ldots,b_n\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $A 
>  = (b_1,\ldots,b_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ the following statements
>   are equivalent:
>
> - $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$
> - $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ is a generator (German: *Erzeugendensystem*) of $\mathbb{R}^n$
> - $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ are linear independent
> - $A\in \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is invertible

But if a basis is previously defined as $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ being (1) a generator and (2) linear independent, how is one of these conditions 1 or 2 sufficient to tell the other? Isn't $$\text{span}\{b_1,\ldots,b_n,b_{n+1}\} = \mathbb{R}^n \quad \text{with}\quad b_{n+1} = \lambda\cdot b_n,\, \lambda\in\mathbb{R}$$
also a generator of $\mathbb{R}^n$ without $b_1,\ldots,b_n,b_{n+1}$ being linear independent? From this equivalence here $b_1,\ldots,b_n,b_{n+1}$ are a generator of $\mathbb{R}^n$, therefore a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and also linear independent – which they aren't.

Comment: $b_1, \ldots, b_{n}, b_{n+1}$ are $n+1$ elements, while $b_1, \ldots, b_{n}$ are exactly $n$ elements. That makes a difference in this statement! It wouldn't be true otherwise.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for your prompt answer – that clears things up!